# OffscreenPageLimit for SlidingTabs?

Tags: java, android

I first started out with Swipeviews using the actionbar which I later found out will be deprecated in Android L so I moved on to "Sliding Tabs".

I have 3 tabs which all contain different websites. When going to the last tab and then again to the first tab, it reloads the tab so if I for instance searched for something I would be back at the homepage.

For swipeviews I used "setOffscreenPageLimit(2);" and it would work without page reload. Now using Sliding Tabs I get the error "Cannot resolve method setOffscreenPageLimit(int)". Are there any other way to make it not reload with Sliding Tabs?

Code:

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Comment: can you show me how you use `For swipeviews I used "setOffscreenPageLimit(2);"` because I do not understand what you want and what you have  achieved?

Comment: @mmlooloo so I have 3 tabs. I have google in each one (just for now) if I for example search for "hello" in the first tab, scroll to the last tab and then back to the first one. I will be at Googles homepage. When using "setOffscreenPageLimit" to 2 it would remember that I searched for "hello" when going back to the first tab.

Comment: @user3740791 : It's unclear what you are trying to do based on the code you have posted - `webView.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` certainly won't work as the `WebView` class doesn't have a method with that name.

Comment: try this: `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

Comment: @Squonk it's kinda hard to explain. Problem: When a tab is not showing on the screen, it unloads the tab. So if I for example searched for something on Google in one tab, it will disappear. What I want: I want to make the app remember all the 3 tabs so the ones which are not active won't unload.

Comment: @mmlooloo "cannot resolve symbol 'viewpager'"

Comment: @user3740791 : I think you are misunderstanding (or misusing) the term "tab". A tab is the thing at the top of the screen - what is generally shown as the main part of the screen (associated with each tab), is tab 'content' or 'views' or 'pages' generically. Also what makes you think the "Swipe View" model is deprecated in Android L? The standard `ViewPager` / `FragmentPagerAdapter` approach is considered a type of 'Swipe View'